# Can I get raw video frames from DirectShow without playback

Tags: windows, directshow, ms-media-foundation

I'm working on a media player using Media foundation. I want to support VOB files playback. However, media foundation currently does not support the VOB container. Therefore I wish to use DirectShow for the same.

My idea here is not to take an alternate path using a DirectsShow graph, but just grab a video frame and pass it to the same pipeline in media foundation. In media foundation, I have an 'IMFSourceReader' which simply reads frames from the video file. Is there a direct show equivalent, which just gives me the frames without needing to create a graph, start playback cycle, and then trying to extract frames from the renders pin? (To be more clear, does DirectsShow support an architecture wherein it could give me raw frames without actually having to play the video?)

I've read about ISampleGrabber but its deprecated and I think it won't fit my architecture. I've not worked on DirectShow before.

Thanks,
Mots

Answer (score 6):

You have to build a graph and accept frames from the respective parser/demultiplexer filter which will read container and deliver individual frames on its output.

The playback does not have to be realtime, nor you need to fake painting those video frames somewhere. Once you get the data you need in `Sample Grabber` filter, or a customer filter, you can terminate pipeline with a `Null Renderer`. That is, you can arrange getting frames you need in a more or less convenient way.

Comment: Thanks for the clue, though I'm not totally sure of how to achieve this. From examples that I've seenon DirectShow, we build a graph, topology and everything,  and then call 'Run' on the manager.The 'Run' method starts video playback cycle. So do you mean in my topology, I put a null renderer and call 'Run' and the Sample Grabber filter would intermittently receive frames for each frame?.I was thinking if it would offer something wherein I would initialize DirectShow with the video file, load necessary decoders and I could repetitively call 'Read' on it and get video sample frames.

Comment: In DirectShow (as opposed to MF) the graph does not manage much communication between filters. As soon as you build graph/pipeline and hit start, the filters are on their own to stream data. That is, to capture the frames you need either your own filter in the pipeline next to VOB container reader (or, alternatively video decoder if you need frames decoded), or otherwise you can use stadnard Sample Grabber filter setup to give you a callback via its `SampleCB` method. Then, as soon as you run the graph, you get all video frames one by one in this callback.

Comment: As I said, you can both obtain raw and/or decoded video frames, depending on whether you include your "grab point" before or after video decoder. You can even have two grabbers there, before and after, and you will have a callback for both raw and decoded video frame.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try implementing as suggested. I've seen examples of ISampleGrabber but am not completely sure how to stop the cycle from rendering. How do the filters stream the data among themselves? In that case who manages the frame rate and time stamps? Is it like the media session architecture of MF where you create a topology and the session manages the streaming of data through the MFTs(Media foundation transforms).

Comment: DirectShow is different from MF. Maybe you will want to read "Overview of Data Flow in DirectShow" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx You can stop rendering by stopping the graph. You can always any time just `Sleep` (well, perhaps you would rather `WaitForMultipleObjects`) within the callback when you want to throttle the streaming.

Comment: Alright, I'll dig in more in DirectShow documents and get back again. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Monogram frame grabber filter](http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/2007/12/16/monogram-frame-grabber-v1001/) to connect the VOB DS filter's output - it works great. See the comments there for how to connect the output to external application.